# Sorting a file by the sum of two columns using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Let's say I have a file (**sample**) which looks like this:

```
Apple - 2750 - 30
Pear - 1000 - 45
Peach - 1245 - 3
Banana - 1500 - 50
```

I want to sort these lines by the sum of the second and third column using shell script.
So after running my shell script I want to see:

```
Apple - 2750 - 30
Banana - 1500 - 50
Peach - 1245 - 3
Pear - 1000 - 45
```

I've managed to get the sum of the two columns:

```
cat sample | awk -F " - " '{sum=$2+$3}{print sum}'
```

Now, how do I sort this file by the sum (I don't want to change the file, only writing it to the terminal)?

Comment: Your life will probably be easier if you make a new file with a 4th column (being the sum).  Then sort on that using standard `sort` command.  Then print only the first 3 columns of the new file to the terminal.

Comment: Yeah, probably, but I don't want to create new files because this script works periodically and I would create a lot of new files..

Comment: You don't need to create any files - you can do all of that in a pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing awk with `sort` and `cut`:

```
$ awk '{print $0, $3+$5}' sample | sort -k6rn | cut -d' ' -f 1-5
Apple - 2750 - 30 2780
Banana - 1500 - 50 1550
Peach - 1245 - 3 1248
Pear - 1000 - 45 1045
```

The above shows the sums but in reality the `cut` cuts them off. You could do it using just GNU awk's `asort`, too.

Comment: blank characters (space and tab) serve as field separators by default for sort... so no need `-t` and `-d' '` is better readable imo

Comment: @Sundeep Valid points, thank you. I throw the space to `sort` always because I keep mixing it up with `cut`'s tab default (which I hate).

Comment: Almost exactly what I'd have written (except I'd have prefixed the sum so as to use a simple `sort -n`): `awk '{print $3+$5, $0}' | sort -rn | cut -d' ' -f2-`